# query with multi group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following Table (id, l_id, f_id, status). I want to write a query which should result in

```
count  |  l_id | f_id |
---------------------
20     | l1    | f1   
----------------------
32     | l1    | f2
----------------------
4      | l2    | f1
```

i.e, i want to get the count of f_id for each specific l_id. If i just had to find the count of f_id without l_id, i could have wrote something

`select count(*), f_id from table groupby f_id` but how can i further enhance to split the count based on the l_id as well ?

Programatically I am thinking to first execute a query which fetches using l_id from the table and then for each l_id i can run the query

`select count (*), f_id where l_id = <l_id> group by f_id` but then i would have to do multiple queries. I was wondering if i can achieve this in one query

Answer (score 2):

The `group by` syntax supports more than one column, so it's very simple:

```
select count(*), l_id, f_id
  from table
 group by l_id, f_id
```

Comment: This query will not return the correct count unless l_id is already unique.

Comment: You know what... I'm totally wrong on this one... not sure what I was seeing earlier. Something about duplicate f_id.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this requirement:

> i want to get the count of f_id for each specific l_id.

You'll need to isolate your l_id and then perform a count on f_id:

```
SELECT a.l_id, count(f_id)
   FROM (SELECT l_id
        FROM table
        GROUP BY l_id) a
INNER JOIN table b ON (a.id = b.id)
GROUP BY a.l_id
```

Comment: don't you think what @sstan has written is accurate ?

Comment: You know what... don't listen to me. It's been a long day and I'm wrong on this one.

Comment: If you are looking for a count of unique records then yes @sstan is absolutely correct. I was looking at record counts which is a different topic. If you think you might have duplicate f_id lines and you want to count the number of actual records per l_id then my query would work.

Comment: Each l_id can have multiple f_ids. and the table can have multiple l_id as well. sstan query is returning what i need but i haven't tested it with extensive data. One other problem with your query is that your query doesn't return f_id value ... which i need to know besides f_id count